# How to validate responses in Data driven testing in Soap ui tool ?

Tags: validation, soapui, assertion, data-driven-tests, data-driven

How to validate responses in Data driven testing in Soap ui tool? Because in Data driven testing, single request will hold many scenarios ( different assertions)and all the scenarios might have different response message or status. Can anyone suggest on how to do this?

Comment: You can write a groovy script in between after every response which will log for any error. So suppose you have 40 request running. After every request run groovy will print error and next will be run after it. Then in logs you can see all the logs. you can name the input as 1 ,2,3,4,5,